# open another view controllers view from right side of the screen

Tags: iphone, uiview, transition

I want to open a viewcontroller from right side of the screen.

That is on doing

> [self presentModalViewController:pvc animated:YES];

I want the another viewcontroller's view to appear as if its sliding from the right of the screen instead of appearing as if it is coming from the bottom of the screen :)

How can I achieve that. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [UINavigationController - Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This lets you organize a hierarchy that will slide in from the side. Or you can play with the [UIView animation blocks](http://objcolumnist.com/2009/07/18/simple-uiview-based-animations-on-the-iphone/). Figure out whats best for your app. If you have several things you will be pushing from the side, like categories, use UINavigationController. If you just have a simple view you want to come in from the side and leave, you'll want to use the UIView animation or other animation methods. The UIView animation will look like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
//code to move view on to screen
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a UINavigationController.

In your app delegate you will have a line that looks like this in `applicationDidFinishLoading`:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Change that line to these:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

Now instead of `[self presentModalViewController:pcv animated:YES];` you can do:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pcv animated:YES];
```

This is the control which gives the "slide in from the right" animation. Plus allows you to better control a view stack and navigation within an app. Its the best way to control navigation in your app.

ps: that navController will leak now - its just like this in my example so you can see what I'm doing. You'll want to make the navController an iVar in the .h of your app delegate so you can release it in `dealloc`. If you release it like it is now then you won't be able to send messages to it.

Comment: hi can you please explain in detail what you mean by "You'll want to make the navController an iVar in the .h of your app delegate so you can release it in dealloc" sorry I am an novice in this field :)

Comment: its ok... :) basically you have two types of variable. You have "local scope" variables. These are objects you declare in a method in your class. They only have scope in that method and can't be accessed from otuside of it. Then there are "global scope" variables. These are objects that you declare in the head of your class (the .h file) and can be accessed throughout the class. The problem with my code above is that the scope is the `applicationDidFinishLoading:` method so if you don't release the object there then there will be a memory leak because you can't access the object again...

Comment: ...elsewhere. So what you really need to do is declare it as a global variable, or an iVar (as I've seen them called... :/). To do this you want to go into your WhateverAppDelegate.h and after the line `@interface WhateverAppDelegate ... {` you want to declare your variable in there. So type `UINavigationController *navController;`. Then in `applicationDidFinishLoading:` change my code to just `navController = [[UINavigationContr... etc` (because you've already declared the variable). Then in the `dealloc` method (at the bottom) put `[navController release];`

Comment: sounds complicated but basically this way you're creating an object that can be accessed from anywhere in the class, so it can be kept in memory until the AppDelegate is dealloc'd (ie: when the AppDelegate object is released itself). So you can have the navigation controller for the whole time your application is running, you can send it messages and such, and then when the application quits (or similar) then its released from memory and theres no memory leak.

Comment: Ok Thank a lot :)  really appreciate your efforts you took to help me :)